# Creating TableViews in Swift with an Array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I'm attempting to use the result of one Rest call as an input for my TableView. 
I've got an array named GamesList[String] that is synthesized in the viewDidLoad() function. This is the viewDidLoad() fuction:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getState() { (json, error) -> Void in
        if let er = error {
            println("\(er)")
        } else {
            var json = JSON(json!);
            print(json);

            let count: Int = json["games"].array!.count
            println("found \(count) challenges")

            for index in 0...count-1{
                println(index);
                self.GamesList.append(json["games"][index]["game_guid"].string!);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the functions for filling the TableView get executed before my GamesList array is filled up. These are the functions that fill the TableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return GamesList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Game", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = GamesList[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = GamesList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

How do I force the tables to get filled up (refreshed) after my array has been filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `self.tableView.reloadData()` after you append your values

```
 getState() { (json, error) -> Void in
        if let er = error {
            println("\(er)")
        } else {
            var json = JSON(json!);
            print(json);

            let count: Int = json["games"].array!.count
            println("found \(count) challenges")

            for index in 0...count-1{
                println(index);
                self.GamesList.append(json["games"][index]["game_guid"].string!);
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it however is not compiling. It's telling me that it "Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments'

What argument should I pass along?

Comment: what is your tableView instance name?

Comment: I created the TableView through Storyboard mode. It's connect to the Outlet: Datasource. After your edit I get the error: 'Cannot invoke 'dispatch_async' with an argument list of type '(dispatch_queue_tl, ()->_)'